# PHP password_hash(), default or custom salt?

Tags: php, passwords, password-encryption, php-password-hash

I am thinking of using password_hash() function to encrypt user passwords. I understand that this function generates salt by default if you don't provide it, and it is even encouraged to use the default salt instead of your own. I am currently weighing in 3 options and can't decide which one to go with so I'd appreciate it if you could help me out.

**1. option: password_hash() with default salt**

```
$passwordInput = $_POST['password'];
$passwordHash = password_hash($passwordInput, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
//INSERT $passwordHash INTO DATABASE
```

**2. option: password_hash() with custom salt**

```
$options = ['salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)];
$passwordInput = $_POST['password'];
$passwordHash = password_hash($passwordInput, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
//INSERT $passwordHash INTO DATABASE
```

**3. option: not using password_hash() at all**

I am basing this option on a post from 2014: [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication?rq=1). Basically if it is a more secure approach than password_hash() I'd use something like this:

```
$salt = uniqid(rand(0, 1000000);
$passwordInput = $_POST['password'];
$password = hash('sha512', $salt . $passwordInput);
//INSERT $password AND $salt INTO DATABASE SEPARATELY
```

Comment: Seem to remember reading in the changelog that the salt option has been deprecated completely in PHP7 - so it's probably best to use the salt that's generated automatically : http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php (near the bottom of the page)

Comment: Option 3 is bad. SHA-512 without a KDF such as bcrypt is too fast. An attacker gaining access to the hashes can quickly run them through a password guessing attack. The article is wrong on this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The really short answer to this question is to use `password_hash()` with the default salt (your first option), custom salt is deprecated in PHP7 because, to quote php.net:

> The salt option for the password_hash() function has been deprecated to prevent developers from generating their own (usually insecure) salts. The function itself generates a cryptographically secure salt when no salt is provided by the developer - therefore custom salt generation should not be needed.

By the same token, your third option, `hash()` should be avoided as again you'll need to generate your own salt.

Comment: This is fine but what confuses me is: If the system generates its own salt, WE don't know what the salt is. If we can't store the sale along with the password hash how can we ever check if a password posted is correct? Without knowing the salt we can't create the same hash again.

Comment: @Ade The salt *is* stored with the hash though, look at the [Return Values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) section in the documentation:- *"The used algorithm, cost and salt are returned as part of the hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it."*

Comment: Thanks, yes, I did not initially see that there is also the function [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) - this handles it all.